# Extra line break when reading from file into a binary search tree

Tags: c, line-breaks, carriage-return

I have an assignment in C where im making a binary search tree for words that i read from a file.
My problem is that there are some newlines what i dont manage to catch and get rid of, therefore they get inserted into my binary tree and it looks all wierd when i print it out. This also make some of the words come up several times as "yellow\n" is different from "yellow" when using strcasecmp.

Does anyone have any suggesteons as to what im doing wrong?

Output from the binary search tree (the extra\n in the middle is not supposed to be there! Neither is the double with, where one ends on a line break in the file i read from)):

use 
Used 
was

whatsoever 
with 
with

** EDIT**
Added the file-reading. I use fgets

```
typedef struct node {
    char word[64];
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} Tree;

Tree* createTree(char *word){
    Tree* current = root;
    current = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    strcpy(current->word, word);
    current->left = NULL;
    current->right = NULL;
    return current;
}

void insertBranch(char* word){
    Tree *parent = NULL, *current = root, *newBranch = NULL;
    int res = 0;

    if (root == NULL) {
        if(word[sizeof(word) - 1] == '\n')
            word[sizeof(word) - 1] = '\0';
        root = createTree(word);
        return;
    }
    for(current = root; current != NULL; current = (res > 0) ? current->right : current->left){
        res = strcasecmp(current->word, word);

        if(res == 0)
            return;
        parent = current;
    }
    newBranch = createTree(word);
    res > 0 ? (parent->right = newBranch) : (parent->left = newBranch);
    return;
}

void readFile(char* chrptr){
    char buffer[200];
    FILE *file = fopen(chrptr, "r");

    if(file == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return;
    }
    char *p, *newStr;   
    while((p = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file)) != NULL){
        newStr = strtok(p, "\",.-<>/;_?!(){}[]:= ");

        while(newStr != NULL){

            insertBranch(newStr);
            newStr = strtok(NULL, "\",.-<>/;_?!(){}[]:= ");
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: how are you reading the words from your file? are you reading the whole line with `fgets()` and then parsing the words with `sscanf()`?

Comment: please also paste the code of how you are reading the file

Comment: Have added my read-file now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `\n` is to act like a delimiter and not part of a word, add `\n` to delimiter list.

```
const char *delims = "\",.-<>/;_?!(){}[]:= \n";  // added \n
char *p, *newStr;   
while((p = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file)) != NULL){
    newStr = strtok(p, delims);
    while(newStr != NULL){
        insertBranch(newStr);
        newStr = strtok(NULL, delims);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i feel kind of silly now as i have spent hours on doing all kinds of magic to make it go away :/